# Fading out animated Unity loading screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to have a simple animated loading screen between my menu scene and the game scene. I am trying to do this by loading the game scene in my loading scene asynchronously. I also want the loading screen to fade in and fade out.

I got the fade-in to work. However, I have two problems which I have been working on for hours, but without any succes. These problems are:

1. I cannot get the fade-out to work. I tried setting the 'allowSceneActivation' to false for my asynchronous loading, however this causes the loading to not occur at all. Removing this line makes the game load, but it then lacks the fade out.
2. The animation works very (and I mean VERY) choppy. I understand that the game is loading stuff, so I expect it to be bad, but it's litterally doing a frame every 2 seconds. I tried using a low thread priority (see code below), but no luck. I found people with similar problems, but the frames turned out reasonable when using a lower thread priority.

This is my code for the loading screen:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LoadIntro : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool loaded;
    private bool fadingOut;
    private bool loading;
    AsyncOperation async;

    void Start(){
        loaded = false;
        fadingOut = false;
        loading = false;
        Application.backgroundLoadingPriority = ThreadPriority.Low;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update() {
        //wait for loading screen to fade in, then execute once
        if (!GameObject.Find ("SceneFader").GetComponent<Image> ().enabled && !loaded && !loading) {
            loading = true;
            async = Application.LoadLevelAsync(mainMenuButtons.leveltoload);
            async.allowSceneActivation = false;
            StartCoroutine (LoadLevel (async));
        }

        //if next scene is loaded, start fading out loading screen
        if (loaded) {
            GameObject.Find ("SceneFader").GetComponent<SceneFadeInOut> ().FadeToBlack();
            fadingOut = true;
        }

        //when faded out, switch to new scene
        if (GameObject.Find ("SceneFader").GetComponent<Image> ().color.a >= 0.95f && loaded) {
            async.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadLevel(AsyncOperation async){
        yield return async;
        Debug.Log("Loading complete");
        loaded = true;
    }
}
```

I have a seperate piece of code for the actual fading, which the code above calls:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneFadeInOut : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fadeSpeed = 1.5f;          // Speed that the screen fades to and from black.

    private bool sceneStarting = true;      // Whether or not the scene is still fading in.

    public bool sceneEnding = false;

    public string scene;

    private Image fadeTexture;


    void Awake ()
    {
        fadeTexture = GetComponent<Image>();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // If the scene is starting...
        if(sceneStarting)
            // ... call the StartScene function.
            StartScene();

        if (sceneEnding)
            EndScene();
    }


    void FadeToClear ()
    {
        // Lerp the colour of the texture between itself and transparent.
        fadeTexture.color = Color.Lerp(fadeTexture.color, Color.clear, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }


    public void FadeToBlack ()
    {
        // Lerp the colour of the texture between itself and black.
        fadeTexture.color = Color.Lerp(fadeTexture.color, Color.black, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }


    void StartScene ()
    {
        // Fade the texture to clear.
        FadeToClear();

        // If the texture is almost clear...
        if(fadeTexture.color.a <= 0.05f)
        {
            // ... set the colour to clear and disable the GUITexture.
            fadeTexture.color = Color.clear;
            fadeTexture.enabled = false;

            // The scene is no longer starting.
            sceneStarting = false;
        }
    }


    public void EndScene ()
    {
        // Make sure the texture is enabled.
        fadeTexture.enabled = true;

        // Start fading towards black.
        FadeToBlack();

        // If the screen is almost black...
        if (fadeTexture.color.a >= 0.95f) {
            // ... reload the level.
            if (scene == "") Application.Quit();
            else Application.LoadLevel (scene);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the issues described above? I've litterally tried every topic I could find, but none of them seem to work. Building my game did not resolve the issues either.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are fading out when scene loading gets done. What are you expecting when loading is done? :)

```
//if next scene is loaded, start fading out loading screen
        if (async.isDone) {
            GameObject.Find ("SceneFader").GetComponent<SceneFadeInOut> ().FadeToBlack();
            fadingOut = true;
        }
```

Obviously it will change the scene and you code doesn't getting enough time to perform fade-out operation. :)

For instance if consider your point. You wrote,

```
//if next scene is loaded, start fading out loading screen
        if (loaded) {
            GameObject.Find ("SceneFader").GetComponent<SceneFadeInOut> ().FadeToBlack();
            fadingOut = true;
        }

        //when faded out, switch to new scene
        if (GameObject.Find ("SceneFader").GetComponent<Image> ().color.a >= 0.95f && loaded) {
            async.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }
```

in `Update`. Here your `loaded` check doing 2 things.

1- Start fading out.

2- Switching scene.

Again, why it should wait for fading it out completely while its getting `loaded` and you are checking `alpha >= 0.95` which should execute at first frame when you get `loaded` to true,  because I believe that in first frame `alpha` would be greater than `0.95`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! That does indeed not make a lot of sense, I have changed it in my code. This does not solve the problem however, async.allowSceneActivation = false still somehow prevents the loading from not happening..

Comment: Thank you again for your help!
During fade out (at the end of the loading) the alpha is in fact going up, because I am using a black overlay (the image component of SceneFader) which is slowly covering the loading screen. The third if-statement will therefore be executed once the fading out (or: fading in of the overlay) has completed.

Comment: I have yet to find a solution, especially for the first problem. I can live with the choppiness I guess.. But I would really like to fix the fade out after the game has loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the initial configuration of your `Image` `fadeTexture`?

Comment: Because you are changing color to black and checking alpha? :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100160/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-timmeh).

Comment: Did you see my replies? I'd love to still solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry I was busy little bit from couple of days. Well, you can tell me now where is your problem now? Still exists?

Comment: Yes, I have been working on other issues, because I had no idea on how to solve the problem. I sent a description in the chat you made.